# websocket : problem connecting to server on ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, docker, websocket

I have an websocket server script written in python (using Flask and socketIO).
When I run the script locally on my computer, I can easily connect to the socket from my phone using the "websocket tester app".

But when i deploy the same script on my ubuntu server(digital ocean cloud), I am not able to connect to it!

I am deploying it using docker, here are the "docker scripts" i use:

```
 docker build -t websocketserver .

 docker run -d -p 5080:8080 --restart always --name my_second_docker_running websocketserver
```

I am running this command to check wheter there are some errors or not:

```
docker logs --tail 500 my_second_docker_running
```

but everything seems to be fine, but still..

Somebody knows what the issue is?

If needed(i dont think so), then here my python script:

```
from aiohttp import web
import socketio
import aiohttp_cors
import asyncio


import asyncio as aio
import logging

# creates a new Async Socket IO Server
sio = socketio.AsyncServer()
# Creates
app = web.Application()
sio.attach(app)


# AIOSerial now logs! uncomment below for debugging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


async def index(request):
    with open('index.html') as f:
        print("Somebody entered the server from the browser!")
        return web.Response(text=f.read(), content_type='text/html')



@sio.on("android-device")
async def message(sid, data):
    print("message: ", data)

@sio.on("device-id")
async def message(sid, android_device_id):
    print("DEVICE ID: ", android_device_id)


@sio.on("disconnected-from-socket")
async def message(sid, disconnected_device):
    print("Message from client: ", disconnected_device)


@sio.on('sendTextToServer')
async def message(sid, data):
    print("message: " , data)
    if data == "hei":
        await sio.emit("ServerMessage", {"Message from server:": "du skrev hei? Da skriver jeg hei tilbake!"})
    if data == "lol":
        await sio.emit("ServerMessage", {"Message from server:": "hehe, funny right?.."})
    else:
        await sio.emit("ServerMessage", {"Message from server:": "Hello There!"})



async def send_message_to_client():
    print("this method got called!")
    await sio.emit("SuperSpecialMessage", {"Message from server:": "MESSAGE FROM SENSOR"})




# We bind our aiohttp endpoint to our app
# router
cors = aiohttp_cors.setup(app)
app.router.add_get('/', index)

# We kick off our server
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("websocket server is running!")
    the_asyncio_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    run_the_websocket = asyncio.gather(web.run_app(app))


    run_both_loops_together = asyncio.gather(run_the_websocket)

    results = the_asyncio_loop.run_until_complete(run_both_loops_together)
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: Did you open your port on your cloud by setting VPC?

Comment: Do i need to do that? I can connect to my database and apache server from outside, so why should i need to do that?

Comment: The cloud may protect you from attack by filter some port by default.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, instead of using `-p 5080:8080`  i could simply just use `-p 5080:8000` so now it works!